# How to send a message to all consumers using Django Channels 3.0.0?

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am trying to develop an interface that contains a section that shows all active users. So, when a user connects to the WebSocket I want to send data to all connected consumers.

Currently, I wrote a code that when the user connects it sends data to the connected user only. I want somehow to make the message be sent to all active users/consumers.

This is the path to my WebSocket handler/view

```
path('test_ws/', websocket.TestConsumer.as_asgi()),
```

And here is the handler

```
class NewsMentionConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

groups = ["newsmention1"]
channel_name = 'news_mention'
active_users = []

async def connect(self):
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.groups[0], self.channel_name)
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(self.groups[0], {
        'type': 'send_updates',
        'text': json.dumps({
            'id': self.scope['user'].id,
            'username': self.scope['user'].username,
            'active_users': self.active_users
        })
    })
    await self.accept()
    self.active_users.append(self.scope['user'])

async def send_updates(self, event):
    # TODO: Make this send to all users/consumers
    await self.send(event["text"])
```

I am facing a problem understanding the examples in django.channels docs and tried using `send_group` function but it doesn't really work. Any suggestions?

#### EDIT: add all users to the same group with unique names.

```
async def connect(self):
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.groups[0], self.unique_name());
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(self.groups[0], { ... });
```

`group_send` still sends the message to the requested user only.

#### EDIT 2: after adding the init function.

Now, I have a channel_name but I am getting a new error when I am trying to send the data to all consumers in the group:

```
class NewsMentionConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

group = "newsmention1"
active_users = []

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

async def connect(self):
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.group,
        self.channel_name,
    )

    await self.channel_layer.group_send(self.group, {
        'type': 'send_updates',
        'id': self.scope['user'].id,
        'username': self.scope['user'].username,
        'some_data_to_all_clients': some_data_to_all_clients()
    })

async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.group, self.channel_name)

async def send_updates(self, event):
    await self.channel_layer.send_group(self.group, event)


'RedisChannelLayer' object has no attribute 'send_group'
```

Any suggestions?

#### EDIT 3:

```
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.group,
            self.channel_name,
        )
        self.active_users.append({
            'id': self.scope['user'].id,
            'username': self.scope['user'].username
        })
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(self.group, {
            'type': 'send_updates',
            'id': self.scope['user'].id,
            'username': self.scope['user'].username,
            'some_data_to_all_clients': some_data_to_all_clients()
        })

    async def send_updates(self, event):
        await self.send(json.dumps(event))
```

Comment: Any reason for the redundant `__init__` method? You shouldn't override it unless you need to. Do you still get a null error with Channel name? The error you posted is different and quite self explanatory. You should call `channel_layer.send(...)` in the `send_updates` method and not `send_group` as there is no such method. Please refer to the tutorials in the docs

Comment: Does `channel_layer.send(...)` supposed to send the data to all consumers in the same group?

Comment: No it doesn't, `self.channel_layer.group_send` does and you already use it. `group_send` broadcasts the message to every channel in the group and each channel contains the `send_updates` method which now sends the message downstream through the websocket connection to the consumers. That is why you need the `send` method to send it to the client

Comment: I will update my code to show how I used `.group_send` in the connection function and `.send` in the `send_updates` function (exactly as you said), it still sending the message to the requested consumer only.

Comment: My bad, it shouldn't be `channel_layer.send` but `self.send` because you're not sending over the channel layer. It would really help if you followed the chat tutorial in the docs as they already do these things correctly there https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_3.html

Comment: My code is exactly like the document you sent. I am using `send_group` and in the `send_updates` I am using `self.send` it doesn't send to all channels.

Comment: Then it's most likely that no other user is connected to that consumer or there is an error somewhere else in your code

Comment: I am not receiving any error and messages sent to a single client instead of all.
I am checking by login from two different accounts first from the browser and second from incognito. Maybe django thought that is the same consumer and that's why it sent only once for a single user?

Comment: You can use the browser dev tools to monitor the messages from the server and see if you are receiving messages

Comment: The problem is that when a user connects to the WebSocket, I accept him, and then I use`send_group` (exactly) to share data with all consumers on his group. When I check the browser dev tools for each user, I see that only one user receives a message and always it is the user who sent the connect request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a bug](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1566) of Django Channels `3.0.0`. It was fixed in `3.0.1`.

Comment: Correct, I started using Django channels exactly in a day between two versions of fixing bugs within one week.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set a static channel name as it is used to identify channels and so have to be unique. The usual practice is to use the channel names generated by Django Channels.
Regarding sending an event to all connected users, you just need to have a group to which you add all channels as they connect and then send the message there. What you are doing already looks similar except the channel name part.

Comment: I tried again by adding all users in the same group name and unique channels names but the send_group function still sends the message to the requested user only.

Comment: Which channel layer are you using? are you sure other users are connected? By the way, don't create your own channel_name, use the one assigned by Django channels. If you want to identify the user, create a separate group for him instead. This approach is better anyway because you will be able to identify multiple connections from the same user

Comment: Currently, I am sure that I am using unique names for each channel/consumer, and all of them in the same group.
What do you mean by 'use the one assigned by Django channels', when I try self.channel_name it always undefined. I am still stuck.

Comment: Then something is wrong with your code. self.channel_name is populated by Django Channels and usually left as it is. Use it and post your code and the stacktrace if there is an error. Also, which channel layer are you using? Can you show the CHANNEL_LAYER setting?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the __init__ on my consumer class, now I have a channel name for each consumer.